# How to put button over row In react-native?

Tags: button, react-native, row

I have text and image in one row. and now I want to put button over the  row with exact size of row.

used `flexDirection: 'row'`

Any help?

Comment: Do you mean you want to make the whole row touchable so that you can respond to any touch event on any part of the row? Will the button have any visible elements? Can you share the UI image?

Comment: @yes I mean whole row touchable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your text and image inside the `TouchableOpacity` component

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => doYourThing()}>
  <Text>{yourText}</Text>
  <Image source={{}} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

If the text and image are already wrapped in a `View`, you can just replace the `View` component with the `TouchableOpacity` component. It takes all the props which `View` takes.

Comment: Thanks of comment that replace View with TouchableOpacity.